# How can I add any event/function on cross mark of search box with knockout.js in IE?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to add event/function on cross mark in search box with knockout.js, couldn't able to find any solution. Anyone have idea how to do it by using only knockout.js?

Comment: Rohan, what's your definition of cross mark and search box? what are you doing with the cross mark that you need your app to react to?  is there some code that you can share that would help illustrate the problem you are having?

Comment: @NathanFisher I don't have code, but I can explain, I have one list on that search is applied. If I type something in search box and clear it by backspace or "X" then I have to click search button or press enter to refresh my list. so wanted to add event on "X", if I type something in search box and click on "X" then it will automatically refresh the list(it will take to first page of list)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific event for this, but input fields do fire `change` and `input` events. So you can either listen to those, or just subscribe to the observable that's bound to the search input. If the new value is an empty string, the input field was cleared and you can do stuff.

```js
function ViewModel() {
    this.searchTerm = ko.observable();
    this.searchTerm.subscribe((newVal) => {
        if (newVal === '') {
            console.log('Input was cleared');
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="search" data-bind="textInput: searchTerm" />
```